# How would I display a List<Item> so they are grouped by one of the properties?

Tags: c#, linq, razor

So I have a `List<SearchResult> Results` that will return multiple results for a single `Category` property, when the `Item` property is different.

So for example the results could be:

```
SearchResult[0].Category = "Food"
SearchResult[0].Item = "Ham"
SearchResult[1].Category = "Food"
SearchResult[1].Item = "Cheese"
SearchResult[2].Category = "Food"
SearchResult[2].Item = "Crackers"
SearchResult[3].Category = "Drink"
SearchResult[3].Category = "Juice"
```

etc.

Now I want to display them like this:

> Items in the Food category include: Ham, Cheese, and Crackers
>
> Items in the Drink category include: Drink

etc.

But this is what I have now:

```
@foreach (SearchResult result in Results)
{
    <p>Items in the @result.Category category include: @result.Item </p>
}
```

Which of course is displaying the data like this:

> Items in the Food category include: Ham
>
> Items in the Food category include: Cheese
>
> Items in the Food category include: Crackers
>
> Items in the Drink category include: Juice

Now I feel like there must be some LINQ magic I can work on that `List` and do this properly, rather than manually coding a loop that separates them off into individual lists.

What's the trick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is using the [group clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) / the [GroupBy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx).

```
var query = from result in Results
            group result by result.Category;
```

and

```html
@foreach (var g in query)
{
    <p>Items in the @g.Key category include:</p>
    <ul>
    @foreach (var x in g)
    {
        <li>@x.Item</li>
    }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Ok I left out some detail I thought would not be important (crap)... but what if there are other values I want to display along with Category before going down into the second foreach? The 'g' var seems to not be letting me access any of them.

Comment: Are those other values the same for each item in a category? Then you can simply use the values of `g.First()` in the outer foreach.

Answer (score -1):

Brute force, but... (all code below untested, but should be more or less right)

```
SearchResult
    .Select(sr => sr.Category)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(c => 
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Items in the " 
                              + c 
                              + " category include: " 
                              + String.Join(",",
                                  SearchResult
                                     .Where(i => i.Category == c).Select(i => i.Item)))
);
```

or GroupBy as suggested by @dtb:

```
SearchResult
    .GroupBy(sr => sr.Category)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(g => Console.Out.WriteLine("Items in the " 
                              + g.Key 
                              + " category include: " 
                              + String.Join(",", g.Select(i=>i.Item))));
```

Comment: Don't know who has downvoted but the first implementation is not so good.